# Must a positive definite function be continuous?

Tags: positive-definite

Let $\Phi:\Omega\times\Omega\to\Bbb R$, with $\Omega\subseteq \Bbb R^d$.  We say that $\Phi$ is positive definite if for every finite set $\{ x_1, x_2,\dots, x_n\}\subset\Omega$ of distinct points the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ whose entries $A_{ij}$ are defined as
$$
A_{ij} = \Phi(x_j,x_k)
$$
is positive definite.

I've seen only example of positive definite functions which are also continuous.  Is there any positive definite function which is not continuous?

Comment: Consider a square wave, displaced to be always positive.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork  So, is such a displaced square wave positive definite?